# Install4J: customize watermark text programmatically

Tags: install4j

Can we customize the install4j watermark text on the install screens programmatically?

For example,

1. In the startup step, we read a file, store its value in an "installer runtime variable",
2. After it, in a "script action", using the previous value to initialize the text used?

Answer (score 0):

To edit the "Watermark" text, go to Installer->Styles, edit the "Standard" style and set the "Text" property of the "Horizontal separator" form component named "Watermark".

[image]

You can set that property to an installer variable, say ${insstaller:watermarkText}. That variable should be pre-defined for the installer. When you change the installer variable, the watermark text will be changed accordingly, even for screens that have already been instantiated.